# Trapping lightrays under nonstandard reflections and/or paths

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, plane-geometry, billiards

Almost every version of trapping lightrays with mirrors is either resolved---usually negatively---or open:

- "It is unknown whether one can construct a polygonal trap for a parallel beam of light": Serge Tabachnikov. [*Geometry and Billiards*](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-30/), p. 116.
- [Can we trap light in a polygonal room?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/237747/6094)
- [Trapped rays bouncing between two convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/a/38320/6094)
- [Trapping light rays aperiodically](https://mathoverflow.net/a/237749/6094): Mitchell, Zachary, Gregory Simon, and Xueying Zhao. "Trapping light rays aperiodically with mirrors." [*Involve, a Journal of Mathematics*](http://msp.org/involve/2012/5-1/p02.xhtml) 5.1 (2012): 9-14.
- [Light rays bouncing in twisted tubes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/70421/6094)
- [Blocking light with mirrored convex objects](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156344/6094)
- [Trapping Light Rays with Segment Mirrors](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/TOPP/P31.html#Problem.31)

However, there are variations in the reflection laws that might change matters:

- [Billiard dynamics with angle of reflection a fraction of angle of incidence](https://mathoverflow.net/q/169296/6094)
- [Billiard dynamics under gravity](https://mathoverflow.net/q/71803/6094)
- [Periodic billiard paths in hyperbolic triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/250282/6094)

My question is:

> ***Q***. Can one "construct a polygonal trap for a parallel beam of light"
>   (to quote Tabachnikov) under a natural different model of reflection and/or paths under gravity?

I think for billiards under gravity the answer is likely *Yes*,
but I have little intuition for reflections at a fraction of angle of incidence.

---

[image: RayDisksReturn]

     

<sup>Trapping a ray between two disks.</sup>

---

[image]

      

<sup>Paths under gravity.</sup>

---

Comment: I don't understand "Almost every version of trapping lightrays with mirrors is either resolved or open." What other alternative is there?